# Is it possible to choose keyboard layout via terminal command?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Lubuntu 13.10. Keyboard model pc 105.
I have 4 keyboard layouts - RU, PL, FR, UA.
Is it possible to choose needed layout by command line in terminal? 
Command `setxkbmap -layout fr` not working for choosing French keyboard layout.

Comment: It is another question. I want to select needed keyboard from 5-7 ones directly in terminal. Directly French (for) example. But there is another answer on link - how to change 1 keyboard from 2. My question is related, but it is exactly different question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch between keyboard mappings, you need to add a setxkbmap command to /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart

To switch between two keyboard mappings with the control+shift keys, Open the terminal and

```
echo '@setxkbmap -option grp:ctrl_shift_toggle "de,us"' | sudo tee -a /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

**Keyboard mapping for 13.10 and beyond**

Since Lubuntu 13.10, the method to choose and toggle keyboard layout has changed. Indeed, lxkeymap application is no longer installed by default, and we have to use Keyboard Layout Handler instead, a plugin for lxpanel.

On Lubuntu default installation, Keyboard Layout Handler appears on the right of the panel, near volume control. It displays a box which describes the current keyboard layout (for example, “US”). To modify keyboard layout settings, right click on it, and choose « Keyboard Layout Handler Settings ». Here you can make some modifications.

By default, the option « Keep system layouts » is checked. Uncheck it to customize your keyboard layout.

[source: Lubuntu community/Keyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

To change the keyboard layout (e.g. to French) in the Linux command line, enter the command:

`loadkeys fr`

The codes occur in various places like `/etc/X11/xkb/`.

Comment: Command loadkey fr also not works in my Lubuntu 13.10 (Keyboard model pc 105). This command don't give any effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with two methods .

1.loadkeys

2.setxkbmap

**Loadkeys**

```
sudo apt-get install loadkeys
```

after installing loadkeys run it as normal user and choose the style you want with

```
loadkeys -v
```

PS: only works on CLI version.

**setxkbmap**

This command you have to run as root user. as a normal user can not do the process with this command.

use it as

```
sudo setxkbmap -layout es
```

If you want to change it to English.

credit goes to : [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1551403)